# passing datatable object var as parameter in EL expression: how to make it robust?

Tags: jsf, datatable, el, page-lifecycle

In [Core JavaServer Faces](http://horstmann.com/corejsf/) we find the following example for deleting rows out of a DataTable, where tableData.names is a list of Name objects:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{tableData.names}" var="name" ... />    
    <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{tableData.deleteRow(name)}" /> 
</h:dataTable>
```

It comes with a warning that this may not delete the correct row if we use request scope and the list changes "between the rendering of the table and the decoding of the response".

> CAUTION: If the value of the data table has *request scope*, be sure that the data does not change between the rendering of the table and the decoding of the response
>   (page 226 of the 3rd edition)

Can anyone explain that quote in terms of the JSF lifecycle? If "render response" is the final phase in the JSF lifecycle, where does "decoding the response" fit in? Do they mean the decoding of the following postback REQUEST (which sends a generated ID by which to identify the row and hence the name object)?

And: how can we implement this in a more robust fashion?

Comment: Please just have one question, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15618842/1065197 just with more detail. Note that you can edit your questions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I can't explain the duplication, but in any case this version is the intended one. I'll remove the other one as soon as I'm sure that no one is currently editing a response.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, interesting question. AFAIK I would use a `@ViewScoped` (or wider) managed bean for these kind of situations.

Comment: This might have happened because you used the browser's back button to edit the newly posted question instead of the therefor provided "edit" link. This way you would only post another question with the edits. P.S. the comment in your deleted duplicate question is noticed. I can't post a new comment on that anymore, but I could still edit my last comment there within the 5-minute grace period ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method expression is not evaluated during the request of displaying the form (the encode step as the book is talking about), but during the request of processing the form submit (the decode step as the book is talking about). The inputs and actions of the datatable row are determined on basis of the table's row index. During processing of the form submit, JSF re-iterates over the data model in order to find the submitted values and the invoked actions.

So, if the `<h:dataTable value>` is tied to a request scoped bean and thus the data model is reinitialized on a per-request basis, then you'll risk the `#{item}` to *actually* reference the item at the wrong index during the processing the form submit, because between the requests of displaying the form and submitting the form, the DB might have retrieved a new item, or have removed another item, which would potentially move the desired item to a different index.

To avoid this, the bean needs to be placed in the view scope so that exactly the same datamodel which is initialized in (post)constructor of the initial request will be preserved across postbacks without the need to reinitialize it during the beginning of every single request and thus potentially containing different items or in a different order. The influence is bigger if loading of the datamodel is tied to a specific request parameter under full control of the enduser like a search query.

An alternative, which is actually a bad one in this particular non-idempotent "Delete this item" case, but a good one for the idempotent "Edit this item" case, would be to use a GET link instead. The desired item is immediately rendered as query string parameter of the `<a>` element.

```
<h:link value="Edit" outcome="edit">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
</h:link>
```

Comment: o.k. so if I understand you correctly, 1. the book should read "between the rendering of the table and the decoding of the **postback**" and 2. using request scope should just plain be avoided when using this technique?